# After page load, button only works when it is clicked the second time

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to create buttons (that are divs) that, when clicked, display other divs. For example, Button01 displays Div01 and Button02 displays Div02. Only one Div can be displayed at a time. I have this part working but I've run into an issue where, after the page loads, the click functions don't work until a button div is clicked once (which seems to do nothing). Following this first click, the button divs all work fine. Why is this happening and how can I make it so that the click functions work right away?

HTML

```
<div id="showOne" class="button" onClick="showOne()">Show One</div>
<div id="showTwo" class="button" onClick="showTwo()">Show Two</div>
<div id="One"></div>
<div id="Two"></div>
```

CSS

```
.button {
    width:70px;
    height:81px;
    background-color:#ccc;  
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}

#One {
    width:70px;
    height:81px;
    background-color:blue;  
    float:left;
    display:none;
}

#Two {
    width:70px;
    height:81px;
    background-color:red;   
    float:left;
    display:none;
}
```

Javascript

```
function showOne(){
    if (document.getElementById('Two').style.display != "none") {
        document.getElementById('Two').style.display = "none";
    };

    if (document.getElementById('One').style.display == "none") {
        document.getElementById('One').style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('One').style.display = "none";
    };
};

function showTwo(){
    if (document.getElementById('One').style.display != "none") {
        document.getElementById('One').style.display = "none";
    };

    if (document.getElementById('Two').style.display == "none") {
        document.getElementById('Two').style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('Two').style.display = "none";
    };
};
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/7BtZn/1/

As you can see, using "No wrap - in ", the buttons only work after a button is clicked once first (which is what is happening on my actual page). Notably, using "onLoad", the buttons don't work at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `.style.display` only gives you the setting if it is currently set directly on the element. It won't give you a result from your style sheet.

To fix it, make the comparison to the default (style sheet) value a comparison to `""` instead of to `"none"`, then set it to `""` instead of `"none"` to return to the default.

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/7BtZn/5/

```
function showOne(){
    var one = document.getElementById('One');
    var two = document.getElementById('Two');

    if (two.style.display != "") {
        two.style.display = "";
    }

    if (one.style.display == "") {
        one.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        one.style.display = "";
    }
}

function showTwo(){
    var one = document.getElementById('One');
    var two = document.getElementById('Two');

    if (one.style.display != "") {
        one.style.display = "";
    }

    if (two.style.display == "") {
        two.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        two.style.display = "";
    }
}
```

I also reduced the code by saving the elements to variables. Much cleaner and less error prone that way.

I removed a bunch of unnecessary semicolons too.

---

Here's an even more DRY version of your code:

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/7BtZn/6/

```
function swapShow(el1, el2) {
    if (el1.style.display != "") {
        el1.style.display = "";
    }

    if (el2.style.display == "") {
        el2.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        el2.style.display = "";
    }
}

function showOne(){
    swapShow(document.getElementById('Two'),
             document.getElementById('One'));
}

function showTwo(){
    swapShow(document.getElementById('One'),
             document.getElementById('Two'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `style` Object doesn't have a value. Change your code to this:

```
<div id="One" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="Two" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Or `display: block;` should you need that instead.

Ideally you should avoid inline `onclick` event handlers and toggle classes using JavaScript rather than abusing the style object - which is in no way scalable.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7BtZn/8/)

```
window.onload = function(){
    var hide = function( el ){ el.style.display = 'none'; },
        show = function( el ){ el.style.display = 'block'; },
        one  = document.getElementById( 'One' ),
        two  = document.getElementById( 'Two' );

    document.getElementById( 'showOne' )
        .onclick = function(){ show( one ); hide( two ); };
    document.getElementById( 'showTwo' )
        .onclick = function(){ show( two ); hide( one ); };
};
```

**Alternatively:**

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7BtZn/9/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="showOne" class="square button">Show One</div>
<div id="showTwo" class="square button">Show Two</div>
<div id="One" class="square hidden"></div>
<div id="Two" class="square hidden"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.button {
    background-color:#ccc;  
    text-align:center;
}

.square {
    width:70px;
    height:81px;
    float: left;
}
#One {
    background-color:blue;  
}
#Two {
    background-color:red;   
}

.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = function(){
    var hide = function( el ){ el.className += ' hidden'; },
        show = function( el ){ el.className = el.className.replace( /\s*\bhidden\b/g, '' ); },
        one  = document.getElementById( 'One' ),
        two  = document.getElementById( 'Two' );

    document.getElementById( 'showOne' )
        .onclick = function(){ show( one ); hide( two ); };
    document.getElementById( 'showTwo' )
        .onclick = function(){ show( two ); hide( one ); };
};
```